# Express $\mathbb{P}(\underline{y}_k\leq Y_k\leq \bar{y}_k \text{ }\forall k) $ in terms of cdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Consider the k-variate random vector $Y\equiv (Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_K)$ with  cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F$.

How can I express in terms of $F$ the following probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}(a_k\leq Y_k\leq b_k \text{ }\forall k)
$$
?

For example, if $K=2$, I know that

$$
\mathbb{P}(a_1\leq Y_1\leq b_1\text{, }a_2\leq Y_2\leq b_2)= F(a_2, b_2)+F(a_1, b_1)- F(a_1, b_2)-F(a_2, b_1)
$$

(Sometimes this is also called rectangle formula)

Is there a way to generalise this to any $K>2$?

---

Thanks to the comment below, I now write the expression for $K=3$

1) I list all the $2^K=8$ vertices

$$
\begin{cases}
a_1,a_2, a_3\\
b_1, a_2, a_3\\
a_1, b_2, a_3 \\
b_1, b_2, a_3\\
a_1,a_2, b_3\\
b_1, a_2, b_3\\
a_1, b_2, b_3 \\
b_1, b_2, b_3\\
\end{cases}
$$

2) Algebraic sum of cdf at each vertex with +1 if the number of $a$'s is even and -1 otherwise

$$
\mathbb{P}(a_1\leq Y_1\leq b_1\text{, }a_2\leq Y_2\leq b_2\text{, }a_3\leq Y_3\leq b_3)= -F(a_1,a_2, a_3)
+F(b_1, a_2, a_3)
+F(a_1, b_2, a_3)
-F(b_1, b_2, a_3)
+F(a_1,a_2, b_3)
-F(b_1, a_2, b_3)
-F(a_1, b_2, b_3)
+F(b_1, b_2, b_3)
$$

Comment: Billingsley's Probability and Measure, Section 12 has a thorough discussion of this.

Comment: Thank you. It is a bit overcomplicated for me. Any easier source?

Comment: Sorry to say that the expression for the probability in $\mathbb R^{k}$ is a bit complicated and I cannot think of a better source.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you, following the book I have written above the expression for $K=3$. Is it correct?

Comment: I think you have got it right.

Comment: It is correct. There are $8$ terms and the term is taken negative iff the number of $a_i$'s in it is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $1_{A\cap B}=1_A\times 1_B$ and $1_{(a_i,b_i]}=1_{(-\infty,b_i]}-1_{(-\infty,a_i]}$.

This leads to:$$1_{(a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n]}=\left(1_{(-\infty,b_1]}-1_{(-\infty,a_1]}\right)\times\cdots\times\left(1_{(-\infty,b_n]}-1_{(-\infty,a_n]}\right)$$

Working out the RHS we get $2^{n-1}$ terms with sign $+$ and $2^{n-1}$ with sign $-$.

The sign is $+$ if and only if the number of $a_i$'s that appear in the term is even.

Taking the integral on both sides gives the equality:$$P(a_1<Y_1\leq b_1,\dots, a_n<Y_n\leq b_n)=\sum_{(c_1,\dots,c_n)\in\prod_{i=1}^n\{a_i,b_i\}}(-1)^{e(c_1,\dots,c_n)}F(c_1,\dots,c_n)$$where $e(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ denotes the cardinality of the set $\{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\mid c_i=a_i\}$